# How to fix : ORA-2091 : OracleXAException: caused by ORA-02292 : XAErr getting integrity constraint violated

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, weblogic12c, xa

I am trying to do a cancel operation from my application which would delete a record from the Database. However in Test environment I am getting an error in the log and the Cancel is failing. The same application when deployed in my localhost, it is working fine without any issue.

I have tried to replicate the issue in my local environment , but it is working there.

**Please note both my local env and test env are pointing to the same database**.

**Error produced in below environment** :

```
App Server : WebLogic 12cR2

DB : 12c

OS : AIX

Java : 1.8
```

**Working in below environment** :

```
App Server : WebLogic 12cR2

DB : 12c

OS : Windows 7

Java : 1.8
```

Error received :

```
Caused by: oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAException: XAErr (100): The
inclusive lower bound oof the rollback codes. ORA-2091 SQLErr (0)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: ORA-02091: transaction rolled back
ORA-02292: integrity constraint (EDOC2.FK_REQ_DOC_TYPE) violated - child record found
```

**Full Error Log** :

```
weblogic.transaction.RollbackException: XAErr (100): The inclusive lower bound oof the rollback codes. ORA-2091 SQLErr (0)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.throwRollbackException(TransactionImpl.java:2104)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.internalCommit(ServerTransactionImpl.java:376)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.commit(ServerTransactionImpl.java:262)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseRemoteObject.postInvoke1(BaseRemoteObject.java:442)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.StatelessRemoteObject.postInvoke1(StatelessRemoteObject.java:20)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseRemoteObject.__WL_postInvokeTxRetry(BaseRemoteObject.java:307)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invokeInternal(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:67)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:21)


Caused by: oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAException: XAErr (100): The inclusive lower bound oof the rollback codes. ORA-2091 SQLErr (0)
        at oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAResource.checkError(OracleXAResource.java:1112)
        at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXAResource.commit(OracleXAResource.java:629)
        at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.commit(DataSource.java:1156)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.XAServerResourceInfo.commit(XAServerResourceInfo.java:1572)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.XAServerResourceInfo.commit(XAServerResourceInfo.java:625)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerSCInfo.startCommit(ServerSCInfo.java:644)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.localCommit(ServerTransactionImpl.java:2402)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.globalRetryCommit(ServerTransactionImpl.java:3386)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.globalCommit(ServerTransactionImpl.java:3291)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.internalCommit(ServerTransactionImpl.java:314)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: ORA-02091: transaction rolled back
ORA-02292: integrity constraint (EDOC2.FK_REQ_NEW_BE) violated - child record found

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:441)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:436)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:1061)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIOtxen.doOTXEN(T4CTTIOtxen.java:169)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CXAResource.doTransaction(T4CXAResource.java:818)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CXAResource.doCommit(T4CXAResource.java:455)
        at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXAResource.commit(OracleXAResource.java:624)
```

Expected result should be it must be working in both the environments, local and test. Please let me know what I am missing out.

Comment: We can't see your code so we don't know how you've implemented this. I'd guess you have different connection pool sizes, and end up in test env with the delete of the parent and child happening on separate connections and thus sessions/transactions, so parent delete can't see that child delete has happened; whereas in dev they happen in the same session/transaction. But, just a guess...

Comment: Ur guess it seems might be correct. But I am not sure how to handle this scenario.

Comment: Force them to use the same connection/transaction, which might not be trivial depending on how you've coded this - but they should be happening together. (You could commit the child delete before starting the parent delete, but that breaks atomicity - if the parent delete still fails for some reason you've lost the child. That's why both need to be in a single transaction.)

Comment: why are you using XA when both point to the same database?